# RailsAdmin hstore and custom lable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Cant configure hstore and custom lable in the same time

Configuration for hstore

Model

```
  store_accessor :list_of_hstore_keys

  rails_admin do
  # Show the string hstore fields
    User.stored_attributes[:options].each do |field|
      configure field
    end
  end
```

Configuration for custom label (in initializer)

```
config.model User do
  list do
    configure :orders_count do
      label 'Has orders'
    end
  end
end
```

and it raise exception

`FrozenError - can't modify frozen Array:`

If I remove one of this configuration another one works fine. But I need both of them.

Maybe someone knows how I can solve this problem.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

I move config from model to initialization RailsAdmin

in result `/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
config.model User do
  User.stored_attributes[:options].each do |field|
    configure field
  end

  list do
    configure :custom_field_from_method
    configure :orders_count do
      label 'Has orders'
    end
  end
end
```